# Android Emulator size has become too big and content on to left side

Tags: android-emulator

I am facing an issue with android emulator when I run AVD device it opens and its size is too big and I have no clue on how to solve this issue. I am attaching the screenshot below of the problem.

Note - I am connecting the emulator with project opened in vscode.

[image: Snapshot of android emulator]

Kindly tell me how to turn emulator to its normal size.